# How to play all audios in the same html5 page?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have several html5 audio players in an html table as

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <audio controls><source src="file1.flac" type="audio/flac"></audio>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <audio controls><source src="file2.flac" type="audio/flac"></audio>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I continue playing file2 when file1 finishes?
Or how can I tell html5 to play only one file on the whole page (if playing a file the one which is playing should be stopped)?

It is like having a list of audios, but I cannot place all files together in a list, as they should be distributed in the table rows.

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript:
in this case detect is playing:

```
    function isPlaying(myAudio1) {
     //do something 

   }else{
    //play Audio2
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio2"); 
    x.play(); 
  }
```

for more details check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp)
i suggest use:

```
 window.onload = isPlaying;//run function on load page
```